# QMimeData::data() function call takes too long to complete

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, clipboard, mime-types

I am trying to retrieve the content stored in clipboard on Linux running Wayland as part of a more complex task and after trial and error I managed to find out that the call to `data()` function takes a couple of seconds, while on x11 it returns instantly.

This is a deal-breaker for me as I have to iterate over many possible mime types. To easily reproduce this issue I included the following code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QClipboard>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class ClipMon : public QThread {

public:
    void run() override {
        QClipboard *board = QApplication::clipboard();
        while (true) {
            const QMimeData *dt = board->mimeData();
            QByteArray bt = dt->data("text/plain");
            qDebug() << bt.data() << "\n";
        }
    }
private:
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    ClipMon thr;
    thr.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I set a breakpoint before the `qDebug()` line and the program resumes execution after a couple of seconds. It sometimes runs instantly, but copying something else to clipboard makes it take a while again.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on Wayland and I tried using both Qt 5.12 and Qt 5.6 .
Do you have any idea what might be causing this? Thank you.

LE: I found out that calling the `data(mimeType)` function with mimeType being "COMPOUND_TEXT" is the culprit here. This call and all subsequent ones with other mimeTypes is going to take a long time. If someone has an explanation I would much appreciate it.

Comment: why the thread my I ask??

Answer (score 0):

I kind can suspect the idea behind the thread so here is my advice for you:

clipboard is in qt a qobject, so you can register your app to signals lke e.g. when the content in the clipboard changes, with this you get rid off the threads and improve the performance of the app

here an example how using lambdas but you can keep using SIGNAL, SLOTS

```
connect(QApplication::clipboard(), &QClipboard::dataChanged, []()
{
    qDebug() << "new data!";
    QClipboard* board = QApplication::clipboard();
    const QMimeData* dt = board->mimeData();
    QByteArray bt = dt->data("text/plain");
    qDebug() << bt.data() << "\n";
});
```

Comment: The application I am developing is a quite complex one, so I call the data() function in lots of places (also from slots), but this does not answer my question. As a side note, do you have any idea why copying to clipboard sometimes leads to dataChanged signal being called HUNDREDS of times?